# Cannot open pdf file that was generated from an InputStream

Tags: java, android, pdf, okhttp

I have an API that provides me with `InputStream` of a pdf file. And my objective is to allow user to view this file with another pdf viewer application.

In order to acheive this, I copied the InputStream to a pdf file that has been created programmatically. Then I tried to open that pdf file.

However, I'm not able to open the pdf file through my application or file explorer. Drive PDF viewer tells in toast that it cannot open the pdf file, Adobe Acrobat tells that the pdf file cannot be accessed, and Mi PDF reader tells that the pdf is in invalid format.

Here's the code inside `onResponse()` of OkHttpClient's call:

```java
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    InputStream inputStream = responseBody.byteStream();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            File file = null;
                            try {
                                file = MyFileUtils.createPdfFile(PdfViewActivity.this);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            MyFileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file);
                            String pdfFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            openPdf(pdfFilePath);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Here's the method responsible for opening pdf:

```java
    private void openPdf(String pdfFilePath) {
        Intent pdfViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfViewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdfFilePath), "application/pdf");
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(pdfViewIntent, "Open this note with");
        startActivity(chooser);
        finish();
    }
```

I created the pdf using `MyFileUtils.createPdfFile()` method. Here's how I implemented it:

```java
    public static File createPdfFile(Activity associatedActivity) throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String pdfFileName = "PDF_" + timeStamp + "_";

        File storageDir = associatedActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        Log.d(TAG, "createPdfFile: storageDir: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());

        return File.createTempFile(
                pdfFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".pdf",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
    }
```

I copied the InputStream to that file using the following method in `MyFileUtils` class:

```java
    // Copy an InputStream to a File.
    public static void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream in, File file) {
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Ensure that the InputStreams are closed even if there's an exception.
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }

                // If you want to close the "in" InputStream yourself then remove this
                // from here but ensure that you close it yourself eventually.
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've implemented the provider in the following way:

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
    <application>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.xyz.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
```

**file_paths.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_documents" path="Documents" />
</paths>
```

**NOTE:**

- The application has necessary read-write permissions. I've tested it programmatically. I'm not including those codes here because it might not be relevant.
- The absolute path of the created pdf file is something like this: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/Documents/PDF_164257_4832620770047519807.pdf`

Comment: `pdfViewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdfUrl)` If that should open the pdf viewer then you should tell it not the download url but path to your file to begin with. Please updat your code first.

Comment: @blackapps in this case I'm sending the path as an argument. It's value is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.package/files/Documents/PDF_172417_2718497032023319439.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

You need to download on device download directory.
Your directory is not visible to other's application that's by its not opening.
Only your application can use this directory.

Not able to comment due to less reputation

Comment: but shouldn't it be okay since I'm using `android:grantUriPermissions="true"` in the provider?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but I see that the `file` you copy the InputStream into seems not be closed before you call `openPdf(pdfFilePath);` which means the pdf viewers get trouble opening it either because it is blocked or not all content has been written into the file.